# Quotient rings example of isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider the rings $K = \dfrac{\mathbb{F}_2 [x]}{(x^4 + x + 1)} $ and $Q = \dfrac{\mathbb{F}_2 [x]}{(x^4 + x^3 + 1)}$. They are isomorphic because the irreducible polinomials have degree 4. But, how can I writte the exactly isomorphism?.
I try writting $K =\{ a+bu \mid a,b\in\mathbb{F}_2 ,\, u^4 + u + 1 = 0 \, (2)   \}$ and $Q=\{ a+bv \mid a,b\in\mathbb{F}_2 ,\, v^4 + v^3 + 1 = 0 \, (2)   \}$.

Comment: Note that $K=\{a+bu+cu^2+du^3:a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{F}_2, u^4+u+1=0\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The roots of $x^4+x^3+1$ are the reciprocals of the roots of $x^4+x+1$.

Let $\beta$ be a root of $x^4+x^3+1$, so that $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^4+x^3+1)\cong\mathbb{F}_2(\beta)$.

Consider the unique homomorphism
$$
\varphi\colon\mathbb{F}_2[x]\to\mathbb{F}_2(\beta)
$$
being the identity over $\mathbb{F}_2$ and such that $\varphi(x)=\beta^{-1}$. What's the kernel of $\varphi$?

Comment: Ok it's do, but how you know that it should be $\varphi (x) = \beta ^{-1}$?. For example, if $\beta $ is a root of $x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x +1$, how can I calculate $\varphi $ in this case?

Comment: @Bohr You need to find in the second field a root of the first polynomial. The first paragraph in my answer explains how I did it in the particular case.